# Dadas 2 medidas buscar la mas cercanas con mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, base-de-datos

Tengo los siguientes datos en una tabla en MySQL:

```
========================================
ancho | alto | precio
1.20  | 1.0  | 156.32
1.20  | 1.10 | 159.35
1.20  | 1.20 | 163.78
1.40  | 1.0  | 164.25
1.40  | 1.10 | 165.25
1.60  | 1.0  | 170.89
1.60  | 1.10 | 172.21
```

Esto se repite N veces hasta llegar a un ancho máximo de 6m y un alto de 5m.

El problema es como obtener el registro más cercano o exacto al ingresar el ancho y el alto, valores que son variables por ejemplo: Un usuario podrá capturar los siguientes valores `ancho: 1.33 y alto 1.18` lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
 SELECT ancho, alto, precio 
    FROM precios
    WHERE ancho >= 1.33 AND alto >= 1.18
    ORDER BY ancho
    LIMIT 1
```

Con esto me esta arrojando los valores más altos a las medidas proporcionadas, lo cual es correcto, pero si ingreso una medida exacta de igual forma me trae las siguientes medidas por encima de los valores proporcionados.

> Como puedo obtener el registro más cercano o exacto?

Y si alguien tiene alguna otra sugerencia para realizar este proceso también es bien recibida.

Estoy utilizando `PHP, MySQL, JQuery`.

Comment: Y si ordenas y te quedas con el primer registro?

Comment: El problema es cuando ingreso un valor exacto ej:1.20 * 1.10 me regresa el más alto o el siguiente que es 1.40 de ancho por 1.10 de alto, lo que comentas  gbianchi funciona pero en valores que no son exactos.

Comment: habria que ver como estas haciendo el order by...

Comment: Edite la pegunta agregado como estoy realizando el Order By

Comment: no ordenes por una sola columna, ordena por las dos ;)

Comment: ya lo hice por ambas de esta manera Order By ancho, alto pero me sigue arrojando el mismo resultado, sin ingreso un valor exacto muestra el mayor no el que le corresponde

Comment: orden ascendente en los dos casos?

Comment: si armas un fiddle podemos ayudarte mejor...

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @gbianchi arma un fiddle rapidamente y aqui le encontramos solucion yo pensaria que con el order by se podia solucionar el problema

Comment: Perdón por la tardanza les paso el link del fiddle [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfd7be/1/0]  @gbianchi

Answer (score 0):

Ordena por área: `ORDER BY ancho*alto`.

Comment: Esta solucion me gusta.. tiene el problema de que si ancho y alto son intercambiables, y tienen distintos precios, podrias llegar a mostrar el equivocado...

Comment: Cierto, espero el comentario del PO aclarando el criterio a aplicar.

Comment: No son intercambiables, siempre se solicitaran las 2 medidas ancho y alto